# Jenkins declarative pipeline docker agent: Timeout run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to improve my build times for my Jenkins jobs and am trying to build docker containers with my dependencies preinstalled.

I have the following (partial) `Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent { 
        docker {
            image 'docker-local.artifactory.com/app-chromium:latest'
            registryUrl 'https://docker-local.artifactory.com/'
            registryCredentialsId 'artifactoryapikey'
        }
    }
}
```

And, according to the logs, jenkins is properly downloading this image. The problem occurs when it tries to run it:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
swarm-sjc01-0270eda05830-0.0.0.0 seems to be running inside container 0270eda05830a074668a5864c52d153377eb67b6406e3912b99f79686cfaca1c
but /home/jenkins/workspace/app_PR-6011-N3O6YOXQAC4KEFHSOKKCS7CFV3GUTIIJAVHDJCR5T7LMXUPU3SLQ could not be found among []
but /home/jenkins/workspace/app_PR-6011-N3O6YOXQAC4KEFHSOKKCS7CFV3GUTIIJAVHDJCR5T7LMXUPU3SLQ@tmp could not be found among []
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /home/jenkins/workspace/app_PR-6011-N3O6YOXQAC4KEFHSOKKCS7CFV3GUTIIJAVHDJCR5T7LMXUPU3SLQ -v /home/jenkins/workspace/app_PR-6011-N3O6YOXQAC4KEFHSOKKCS7CFV3GUTIIJAVHDJCR5T7LMXUPU3SLQ:/home/jenkins/workspace/app_PR-6011-N3O6YOXQAC4KEFHSOKKCS7CFV3GUTIIJAVHDJCR5T7LMXUPU3SLQ:rw -v /home/jenkins/workspace/app_PR-6011-N3O6YOXQAC4KEFHSOKKCS7CFV3GUTIIJAVHDJCR5T7LMXUPU3SLQ@tmp:/home/jenkins/workspace/app_PR-6011-N3O6YOXQAC4KEFHSOKKCS7CFV3GUTIIJAVHDJCR5T7LMXUPU3SLQ@tmp:rw -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat icm-docker-local.artifactory.swg-devops.com/app-chromium:latest
ERROR: Timeout after 10 seconds
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
```

Does anyone understand why it times out? If i provide a dockerfile instead (agent { dockerfile: true }) it builds fine. Not that this is not using the script like pipeline syntax but the newer declarative format.

Comment: are you sure the image exist ? did you verify it from the jenkins slave that run the job

Comment: I have not tried from the jenkins slave (i don't have access to it) but the logs prior to this error show it being downloaded from the appropriate location.